# Show xml in TextArea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show xml in TextArea.

I user the following code:

HTML:

```
<textarea readonly id="blaId" rows="20" style="width:100%;  resize:none";></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("blaId");

elm.innerHTML = xmlStr;
```

It works in FF but not in IE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why you use `.innerHTML`. Textareas cannot contain HTML :-?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
elm.value = xmlStr;
```

Comment: it happens to everyone :-) -- @Erik, rmemeber to select accepted answers when you can :-D